# in Java, when would I put a variable inside a loop when I would not?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

```
 public int solve(int A) {
        
        int primeCount = 0; 
        for (int i =2; i <=A; i++){
            int count = 0;                 --> putting inside for loop works
            for(int j = 1; j<=A; j++){
                if(i%j == 0){
                    count++;
                }
            } if(count==2){
                primeCount++;
            }
        }return(primeCount);       
    }
}
```

---

When i put the count variable outside for loop it doesnot work.. WHY? ideally the scope of count variable in parent level, so it can be accessed by child scope.

```
    public int solve(int A) {
        int count = 0;              --------> variable outside.
        int primeCount = 0; 
        for (int i =2; i <=A; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j<=A; j++){
                if(i%j == 0){
                    count++;
                }
            } if(count==2){
                primeCount++;
            }
        }return(primeCount);
```

1st approach works , second approach doesnot. why?

Comment: both work, but you need to keep in mind that you reset the value of count in the first example, and you don't in the second

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, each iteration through the loop is getting a new variable named `count` that is initialized to 0, *each time time through the loop*. In other words, `count` resets for each loop iteration.

On the other hand, the second example only creates a single variable `count` and initializes it *only once*. That means each iteration through the loop, the value of `count` is kept from the previous iteration, so it accumulates.

The scope of local variables is very important, this is a good example of that.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot for making it clear.